# EditText height in listview doesnt match row height

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, margin

I have a veiw similar to the CustomAdapter example that is used in my adapter for my listview:

```
class FooView extends LinearLayout
{
    EditText mInputBox;

    public FooView(Context context)
    {
        this.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);
        this.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
        mInputBox = new EditText(context);

        // formatted to fit on screen
        float dip = 
            TypedValue.applyDimension(
                COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 
                48.0f, 
                getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        LayoutParams lp = 
            new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
                (int)Math.ceil(dip), 
                1.0f);
        lp.setMargins(0,0,0,0);

        addView(mInputBox, lp);
    }
}
```

and yet I have a space underneath the EditView in each row:
[image: wtf]

I extend FooView and add an ImageButton in the top case (not added in picture). In that view, the ImageView fits to the row perfectly.

```
ImageButton b = new ImageButton(context);
b.setImageResource(R.drawable.foo);
b.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE); //also tried FIT_XY didnt notice a difference
addView(b, new LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
```

The dimensions of the ImageButton are:

- ldpi:  32 x 32px
- mdpi: 48 x 48px (where i got the 48 for the EditText)
- hdpi: 72 x 72px
- xhdpi: 96 x 96px

why does my EditText not scale properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess you're having issues with the background image for the EditText.  Explicitly set the background to a color or XML resource, and see if that changes the situation.

I'd also see if WRAP_CONTENT works instead of a fixed height number, and if so, play around with options after that.

If none of that works, make sure you set padding AND margins on both the custom layout and the EditText to be zero.

Basically the idea is to try these things, get a positive result, then you can remove things one by one to see what really made the change.

Comment: I want the EditText's height to be more than wrap_content (specifically, the size of my ImageButton) Not every row has an image button, though

Comment: I understand, but you need to pinpoint the issue then work back.  If "wrap content" fixes the size issue, but specifying the size breaks it, you probably need to create your own background image.  Something like that.

Comment: It was the background image, I am going to just leave it transparent for editable ones and gray for disabled ones i suppose.

Comment: Might be able to create a 9-patch that works, or do an XML resource with some rounded corners and gradient fill (if that's your thing).